# how to check whether the point is inside or not

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, computational-geometry

When the line segments that form closed shape is given how to check whether the given point lies inside the diagram or not

for example
[image]
AB ,BC ,CD,DE,EA are the line segments given and i know the co-ordinates of endpoints each line segment . Now how to find whether a given point is inside the diagram or not ?

My approach:
 By using ray casting or winding number for checking whether the point is inside or not . But i am struck at "how to find the vertices of polygon"

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/217578/how-can-i-determine-whether-a-2d-point-is-within-a-polygon) link and [this](http://alienryderflex.com/polygon/) one seem relevant. But it appears to me that your problem isn't with using ray casting or winding numbers, but how to convert a set of line segments to a polygon. Is this correct?

Answer (score 0):

You need to find the equations of your segments, and try parallel lines.

If  a point is inside a triangle every line parallel to a side of triangle and passing through that point will intersect  the other two sides at points between vertices.

On the other hand for a point outside the triangle one of the lines parallel to the three sides do not intersect the triangle at all.

Same is true for the pentagon.

Comment: The above only seems to work for convex polygons.

Comment: That is what I meant, you need to check each triangle and the pentagon which are convex.

Comment: The above methld won't work for every case ... Sometimes the diagram may be concave also

Comment: I agree we have to divide the region into conves subregions and work with each section separately.

Comment: i think this method is more complicated to implement and have more time complexity. I am searching for efficient algorithm

Comment: yes it is very time consuming. Thanks for your attention and understanding.